# Springboot dependency Injection failed in hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I have came up with strange Problem I have to inject Spring Managed dependency in an Entity class i have tried it but dependency is `null`,what I am doing wrong can't figure out.

I have a dependency of a utility class that is marked as component and I can access it form controller and service class but not in entity am i missing some jars that i don't know of because it is spring-boot?
here is code:

```
@Table
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
@Component
public class LoginBot extends Bot implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public LoginBot() {}

    @Autowired
    SelUtil util;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> test() {
        Map<String, Object> returnMap=new HashMap<>();
        util.selectBrowserAndPlatform(this);
        return returnMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to inject a bean in an entity class? Entities should be simple POJO and nothing more. What should `SelUtil` do?

Comment: i am creating few routine work and that routine work is different depending on call
i need a single call with different implementation, yes i have thought for strategy design pattern but how in hibernate i can accomplish that because i needed that thing in db also

Comment: Still I don't understand why you need `SelUtil` in an entity that shouldn't have logic. You should move your logic in a service which will create the appropriate entity and then pass it to a dao/repository to persist it.

Comment: Yes there is another way that i can write whole lot of code in test() method that makes it look very shabby so i avoided and made a class instead of writing whole code into different classes because there are many common methods that i will eventually have to group and module it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It Is Not Possible for now.
But there is a patch work with the help of Spring  with adding an extra layer of Service class Between dao and controller that worked for me.
I have made some changes:

1. added `@Transient` annotation in member variable in `Bot class(super class)` so child will have get it anyhow and added an abstract method that is `test()` also.
2. Added a service Interface `BotRepoCustom`  which has method `Bot getBotWithTransientFields(Long id);`
3. Implementing that service class `BotRepoCustomImpl`

Now when I get Bot with Spring Dependency with `BotRepoCustomImpl` class i can Use it directly.
For now patch works and no Static methods.
If you want working Code I can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the spring does not postprocess entity classes, so it will not autowire anything, entities are not spring context beans,  and also putting some util class into an entity bean is a really bad practice. If you really need to use some utils, maybe just add static methods into it?

Comment: that leaves me that i can tell spring to post process few beans
it it possible
having many static methods is also bad programming practice because  if it scales to a level the static will take extra space

Answer (score 1):

Entities are not spring beans, creation is not managed by spring container. They are created by persistence provider. You cannot use autowire and component annotation here.

Adding SelUtil to an entity means you want to persist it. It is really so?

Comment: Not by writing your own post processor in spring such that it can inject its dependency into that

Comment: any help on that is appreciated @peter

Comment: You got the same answer by 3 people. Think about it.

Comment: No as the name suggest it is a util class which is attached to bot entity which is @transient for now